# Angular app in AKS with App Gateway fails on subpaths

Tags: angular, azure-aks, azure-application-gateway

I have an AKS cluster with Azure Application Gateway configured in front.
In kubernetes a have a container running nginx which is hosting my Angular 9 app.

The Gateway is configured as follow.

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: azure/application-gateway
    appgw.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-private-ip: "true"
spec:
  rules:
  - host: client.myhost.com
    http:
      paths:
      - pathType: Prefix
        path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: client
          servicePort: http
```

When I navigate to http://client.myhost.com everything is working fine. Angular app will rewrite url to http://client.myhost.com/home. But if I go to http://client.myhost.com/home directly I will get a 502 (Bad gateway) from Azure Application Gateway. I have a lot of nested routes configured in Angular so I need this to work.

The Angular app was previously hosted on IIS, and here I had to add some configuration to Web.config in order to get this to work.
Do I need to do something similar in NGINX?

`<base href="/" />` is added to `index.html`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was my solution to the problem:

**ConfigMap**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: nginx-cm
data:
  default.conf: |
    server {
      server_name   devicekit;

      root          /usr/share/nginx/html ;

      add_header    X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";

      location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html?$args;
      }
    }
```

**Deployment**

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: serviceA
  labels:
    app: serviceA
    release: serviceA
spec:
  revisionHistoryLimit: 0
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: serviceA
      release: serviceA
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: serviceA
        release: serviceA
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: serviceA
          image: "serviceA:latest"
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          ports:
            - name: http
              containerPort: 80
              protocol: TCP
          volumeMounts:
          - name: config-volume
            readOnly: true
            mountPath: /etc/nginx/conf.d
      volumes:
      - name: config-volume
        configMap:
          name: nginx-cm
```